# Subscribing to an observable from within a service vs from within a component

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

**Angular 5**

I have a service that contains a method addVal() that makes an HTTP call using an observable.

There is a component from which the addVal() method is being called. Is there any difference (functionality-wise as well as design-wise) in calling the subscribe() method in the component versus in the service?

Comment: its then when .subscribe gets executed for cold observable  , the http request would be made, and you write definition of next/error/complete function inside of it.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My rule of thumb is that I always write services as a `thin layer`.

They usually contain only a dependency injection for `HttpClient` and `HttpHeaders`, and I create just calls to the API endpoints there.

Subscription and data is usually handled by components, since you might want to use different parameters while calling your API.

For that reason alone, it's better to have a slimmer service, and 'fatter' component that does all the logic relevant to itself.